# If $\tau$ is a name, is $\{\sigma:\Vdash \sigma=\tau\}$ a proper class?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Fix some (atomless) poset $\mathbb P$. Let $V^\mathbb{P}$ be the class of $\mathbb P$-names and $\tau\in V^\mathbb{P}$. Consider the collection
$$
\{\sigma\in V^\mathbb{P} : \Vdash_\mathbb{P} \sigma=\tau\}
$$
**My question is:** Can this collection be a proper class? I've always believed the answer to be "yes", but I'm struggling to actually prove this.

If $\tau=\emptyset$, then obviously the only name which is forced to be equal to $\tau$ is $\tau$ itself. Indeed, suppose $\sigma\neq \emptyset$, say $(\vartheta,p)\in \sigma$ for some $p\in\mathbb{P}$. Then $p\Vdash \vartheta \in \sigma$, so $p\Vdash \sigma\neq \tau$ and thus $\not\Vdash \sigma=\tau$.

Also, the above is false if we're taking the Boolean algebra approach to forcing. Indeed, since we have access to the bottom element $0$ saying false, we can consider, for any $x\in V$,
$$
\sigma_x=\{(\check x,0)\}\cup \tau
$$
Then $\{\sigma_x:x\in V\}$ is a proper class, and $\|\sigma_x=\tau\|=1$ for every $x$.

It is also false if we replace $\Vdash$ by $p\Vdash$ for some $p\in\mathbb{P}$. Indeed, if $p,q\in \mathbb{P}$ and $p\perp q$, put $\sigma_x=\{(\check x, q)\}$ for $x\in V$. Then $p\Vdash \sigma_x=\emptyset$, and the $\sigma_x$ are pairwise distinct.

I've thought about arguing that
$$
\forall \tau\in V^\mathbb{P} \exists X_\tau\forall \sigma\in V^\mathbb{P} [\sigma \in X_\tau\iff \Vdash \sigma=\tau]
$$
by $\in$-induction. Say $\tau\in V^\mathbb{P}$ and the statement holds for every $\sigma$ of smaller rank. Put $X=\bigcup\{X_\sigma:\sigma\in\text{dom}(\tau)\}$. Suppose there is a proper class of names which are forced to equal $\tau$. Pick a name $\vartheta$ with $\text{dom}(\vartheta)\setminus X\neq \emptyset$ and $\Vdash \vartheta=\tau$. There is some pair $(\pi,p)\in \tau$ with $\pi\not\in X$. We know that $\not \Vdash \pi=\sigma$ for every $\sigma\in \text{dom}(\tau)$, but this is not enough to derive a contradiction, because we only have $p\Vdash \sigma \in \tau$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class is a proper class if $\mathbb{P}$ is atomless.
Let $p$ and $\sigma$ be such that
$\{\mu: p\Vdash \mu=\sigma\}$ is a proper class.
Now consider $\rho=\{(\sigma,p)\}$. If $p\Vdash \mu=\sigma$ and $\rho':=\{(\mu,p)\}$, then

1. $p\Vdash \rho=\rho'$ (In fact, $p$ thinks $\rho$ is a singleton whose element is $\sigma$, and
2. If $q$ is incompatible with $p$, then $q\Vdash \rho=\rho'=\varnothing$.

Hence $\{r:r\Vdash\rho=\rho'\}$ contains a dense subset, namely $$\{r: r\le p \lor r\perp p\}.$$
Thus $1\Vdash \rho=\rho'$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two questions though: in your first paragraph, did you mean atomless? I was under the impression that separative meant $p\not\le q\implies \exists r\le p (r\perp q)$. In your second paragraph, what is the role played by $\tau$?

Comment: @Reveillark $\tau$ is a typo, so I removed it.

Comment: @Reveillark I thought that being separative is necessary, but yes, being atomless suffices.